# desktop shell shortcut in explorer sidepanel

Tags: windows, windows-10, shell, windows-explorer, shortcuts

I'm on Windows 10 Pro N v.1803 (build 17134.648)

This shortcut in windows file explorer side panel leads to desktop:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JaIf.png)

But when you open it, it doesn't show you any desktop icons.

This can be solved to navigating to shell shortcut: `shell:desktop`

**My question**: How do I change this shortcut in side panel so it leads to `shell:desktop` instead of what it does right now.

I tried Winaero Tweaker but it won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The folders under **This PC** aren't 'shortcuts' in the common sense, but namespace entries that link to file system folders. The Shell [namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/namespace-intro) on a Windows PC is rooted at the *virtual* **Desktop**. This is illustrated by the Navigation pane in Explorer if you enable the Navigation pane setting '**Show all folders**':
[image: Navigation Pane: Show all folders]

As you can see, **This PC** is a 'sub-folder' of the **Desktop**. If **Desktop** under **This PC** linked back to its grandparent, you would have an infinite loop!

The easiest way in Explorer to view the root, virtual Desktop folder is using the drop-list from far-left '>' on the Address bar:
[image: Desktop folder drop-list]

Keith